# Combine 2 columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I combine these 2 columns together? Ie, I want to remove the NAN and shift Column 1(a series) into Column 0 (a dataframe)

```
                                                     0              1
A    *aasvfasfdb                                                  NaN
1                                                  NaN   456,0.002121
2                                                  NaN   567,0.005298
3                                                  NaN   345,0.006192
4                                                  NaN   345,0.004532
```

I have tried different entries of the drop method ie, `drop(columns=0, inplace=False)` but they either replace one column or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.combine_first()`:

```
In [198]: df['0'].combine_first(df['1'])
Out[198]: 
0     *aasvfasfdb
1    456,0.002121
2    567,0.005298
3    345,0.006192
4    345,0.004532
```

Comment: @jezrael Should I delete my answer?

Comment: So I was wrong, answer is what OP need.

Comment: @jezrael Should we remove the question as dupe?

Comment: no, it is not possible, because accpeted ;)

Comment: @jezrael No, I am asking if you can remove the duplicate and reopen the question. Is that possible?

Comment: No, mainly because it is correct dupe.

Comment: First was wrong, now I change it.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for the info.